# The Akroan War plus Glorious Protector?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So, I had cast [The Akroan War](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=The%20Akroan%20War) and stole an opponent's [Etali, Primal Storm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Etali%2C%20Primal%20Storm). A few turns later, I swung, used Etali to steal an opponents [Glorious Protector](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Glorious%20Protector), I exile all my tapped creatures (because the final chapter was imminent) including Etali. Next turn, The Akroan War got its final lore counter, after which I had to sacrifice it. This leads me to my two questions:

1. Does Etali stay exiled with GP?
2. If so, under whose control does it return to if GP goes away?

Answer (score 4):

The relevant part of Glorious Protector's text is:

> When Glorious Protector enters the battlefield, you may exile any number of non-Angel creatures you control **until Glorious Protector leaves the battlefield**.

In the situation you describe, Glorious Protector hasn't left the battlefield. (It doesn't do 3 damage to itself because it's not tapped and even if it did, it has 4 toughness, so it doesn't die.) Therefore Etali remains exiled.

The Akroan War leaving the battlefield does not matter. It would return Etali to opponent's control if Etali were still on the battlefield, but it isn't, so nothing happens.

If/When Glorious Protector leaves the battlefield though (which will have to happen via some other effect, e.g. a removal spell targeting it) then Etali returns to the battlefield under your opponent's control. See [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/52832/a-question-about-flickering-a-stolen-creature).

Answer (score 2):

> Does Etali stay exiled with GP?

Yes. Actually, once Etali is exiled, The Akroan War's effect ends; "control" only affects permanents or things on the stack:

> 108.4. A card doesn’t have a controller unless that card represents a permanent or spell; in those cases, its controller is determined by the rules for permanents or spells. See rules 110.2 and 112.2.

This also point to an answer to

> under whose control does it return to if GP goes away?

which is "your opponent":

> 110.2. A permanent’s owner is the same as the owner of the card that represents it (unless it’s a token; see rule 111.2). A permanent’s controller is, by default, the player under whose control it entered the battlefield. Every permanent has a controller.